# Compute and insert multiple value into column in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have the picture as following:

[image]

I want to get the value on textbox to addtion with each value on the each column. After that insert the total value into the cells of new column (Distance) but it is seems incorrect process. Please refer my code as following:

```
int sum =0;

private void btnClassification_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{               
    try
    {                            

        dataGridView.Columns.Add("DISTANCE", "DISTANCE");  //add new column             
        int temp,col1, col2, col3,col4,col5;
        col1 = Convert.ToInt16(txtCustAge.Text);
        col2 = Convert.ToInt16(txtCustGender.Text);
        col3 = Convert.ToInt16(txtIssueDate.Text);
        col4 = Convert.ToInt16(txtCustAnnSalary.Text);
        col5 = Convert.ToInt16(txtCustCrlimit.Text);
        for (int rows = 0; rows < dataGridView.Rows.Count; rows++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < (dataGridView.Rows[rows].Cells.Count)-2; col++)
            {
                temp = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView.Rows[rows].Cells[col].Value.ToString());
                sum = sum + ((col1-temp)*(col1-temp) + (col2 - temp)*(col2 - temp) + (col3 - temp)*(col3 - temp) + (col4 - temp)*(col4 - temp) + (col5 - temp)*(col5 - temp));                                                                  
            }
            this.dataGridView.Rows[rows].Cells[6].Value = sum;   // insert total amount into new column                 
            sum = 0;                    
        }            
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please try again !" + ex);
    }
}
```

Please help to advise for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should solve your problem.

```
dataGridView.Columns.Add("DISTANCE", "DISTANCE");  //add new column             
int temp, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5;
col1 = Convert.ToInt16(txtCustAge.Text);
col2 = Convert.ToInt16(txtCustGender.Text);
col3 = Convert.ToInt16(txtIssueDate.Text);
col4 = Convert.ToInt16(txtCustAnnSalary.Text);
col5 = Convert.ToInt16(txtCustCrlimit.Text);
for (int rows = 0; rows < dataGridView.Rows.Count; rows++)
{
    sum = col1 - Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView.Rows[rows].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    sum += col2 - Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView.Rows[rows].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    sum += col3 - Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView.Rows[rows].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
    sum += col4 - Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView.Rows[rows].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
    sum += col5 - Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView.Rows[rows].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
    this.dataGridView.Rows[rows].Cells[6].Value = sum;   // insert total amount into new column                 
    sum = 0;
}
```

In your code you made a mistake while you are going through the column list for each row. You are adding all differences (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 - column value) to sum instead of only adding the difference of the current column.

Comment: Hi Ben. Thank you for your advise.It work well on my program. Thank you.